# has_one in a has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an association I'm struggling with. I have a Department model, which can have many staff members, one of which is the manager.

I need to be able to call.

Department.staff - and get a collection of all staff including the manager.
Department.manager - and get the manager.

User.department - and get the users department, whether they are staff or manager.
User.is_manager - and get a boolean as to whether they manage a department or not.
User.manages - get the department they manage.

What is the best of setting up this association? I have currently started with something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :department
      has_one :manages, :class_name => 'Department', :foreign_key => :manager_id
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "User"
      has_many :staff, :class_name 'Users'
end
```

The problem that I have with this, is that I have to add the manager both as the manager and as a member of staff, which feels a little clumbsy - but perhaps I'm being picky?

Can anyone suggest some better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this association:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :staffs, class_name: "User"
  has_one :manager, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "manager_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
end
```

Make sure your `User` table has a column called `manager_id`, and a column called `department_id`. If you have a boolean column called `manager` in your `User` table, you will have a method `manager?` to check whether user is manager or not.

To do what you want:

```
@department = Department.find(1) # Find department with id = 1
@department.staffs # Get all staffs of department

@department.manager.name # Get name of manager of department

@user = User.find(1) # Find user with id = 1
@user.department.name # Get name of department which user belongs to
@user.manager? # Return value of manager column
```

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to move the manager_id into department?

belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "manager_id"

Comment: it's up to you, has_one and belongs_to are just different about meaning and where to place foreign_key

Comment: Hello Guys. In this situation would calling Department.staffs include the manager?

Comment: manager is still be user, if manager belongs to department, they will be got too.